# How to create an instance of an typeof Class variable of an abstract class in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I am working on a Node JS TypeScript project. I will just walk you through the code first because it would be easier for me to explain.

I have a class as follow

```
export abstract class RequestValidator {
  abstract getSchema(req: Request, res?: Response): joi.ObjectSchema;
}
```

Then I have a concrete class that extends the abstract class above.

```
class LoginFormValidator extends RequestValidator {
  getSchema(req: Request, res?: Response): joi.ObjectSchema {
    return {
       email: joi.string().required(),
       password: joi.string().required()
    } as joi.ObjectSchema; // this is just dummy code
  }
}
```

What I would like to do is that, I want to pass the type of a class that extends `RequestValidator` to a function and create an instance of it.

Something like this.

```
// this is purely a dummy code
const validateRequest = (validatorClass: typeof RequestValidator) => {
   // here I want to create an instance like this `new validatorClass`
}
```

As you can see in the dummy code above, the comment suggests what I am trying to achieve. I will pass `LoginFormValidator` to the function like this.

```
validateRequest(LoginFormValidator);
```

How can I do that? Or is there any other alternative to what I am trying to achieve? Basically I don't want the client to create an instance of the class. I would rather create the instance within the `validateRequest` function instead. The client still should be aware of the contract of `RequestValidator`.

Comment: Would using an [Abstract Construct Signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#abstract-construct-signatures) work? https://tsplay.dev/wj00Ym

Comment: @Oblosys minor correction: that's not an abstract construct signature; it's just a regular [construct signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#construct-signatures).

Comment: @WaiYanHein Good to hear, I can write it up as an answer if you like.

Comment: @jcalz You are right. The section title "Abstract Construct Signatures" in the documentation is slightly confusing as it is not actually about abstract construct signatures.

Comment: @Oblosys if you could write up the answer, that would be great. I can upvote and accept the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The (somewhat inconveniently named) documentation section [Abstract Construct Signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#abstract-construct-signatures) shows exactly this use case. Instead of using `typeof RequestValidator` as the parameter type for `validateRequest`, you can use a [construct signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#construct-signatures) that produces an instance of a class that derives from `RequestValidator` (i.e. `new () => RequestValidator`). This will allow you to pass `LoginFormValidator` to  `validateRequest` and instantiate it there. It will also correctly disallow passing the abstract class.

```
const validateRequest = (validatorClass: new () => RequestValidator) => {
  const requestValidator = new validatorClass()
  const test = requestValidator.getSchema({} as Request)
  // const test: joi.ObjectSchema<any>
}

validateRequest(LoginFormValidator); // Works.
validateRequest(RequestValidator); // Fails on the abstract class, as desired.
```

[TypeScript playground](https://tsplay.dev/ND8dzN)

As I mentioned, the documentation is a bit confusing, since as jcalz pointed out it, it uses a regular construct signature rather than an abstract one. With an abstract construct signature it would be `(validatorClass: abstract new () => RequestValidator) => ..`, which is precisely what we don't want here.

Answer (score 0):

In TypeScript, you cannot create an instance of an abstract class directly because an abstract class is intended to be a base class for other classes to extend from and cannot be instantiated on its own. However, you can create an instance of a typeof Class variable of an abstract class using a derived class that extends the abstract class.

```
abstract class Animal { abstract makeSound(): void; }
class Dog extends Animal { makeSound(): void { console.log("Woof"); } }
const AnimalClass: typeof Animal = Dog; const animalInstance = new AnimalClass();
animalInstance.makeSound(); // Output: "Woof"
```